# Write the regular expression of the language that the DFA accepts.

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I am given a DFA and I have tried to write the regular expression of the language that it accepts.

This is the DFA that I am given:

[image]

I have found some words that the DFA accepts: `000,111,01001,101110`.
I noticed that it accepts an odd numbers of `0`s,an odd number of `1`s, and any word of the form `01/ 01/ 101` and so on.

So I thought that the expression should be of the form $((0 \{ (00)^{\star},1^+\})^{\star} (1 \{ (11)^{\star},0^+\})^{\star})^+$.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Let me show you a systematic approach. Think of each of the state names as an abbreviation for a regular expression corresponding to the set of words that end at that state when starting from the initial state. Since $B$ and $C$ are the acceptor states, we want the expression $B+C$. (I’ll use $+$ instead of a comma for *or*; I use $\lambda$ for the empty word.)

The first step is to write down equations showing how we reach each of $A,B$, and $C$ in at most one step. Since $A$ is the initial state, we reach it on an input of $\lambda$. We also reach it if we’re in state $B$ and get an input of $0$, or if we’re in state $C$ and get an input of $1$. These are the only ways to reach it in at most one step, so $A=\lambda+B0+C1$: to get from $A$ to $A$, we can read the empty word, we can read any word that gets us to $B$ and then a $0$, or we can read any word that gets us to $C$ and then a $1$. If you perform the same analysis for states $B$ and $C$, you get the following system of equations:

$$\begin{align*}
A&=\lambda+B0+C1\\
B&=A0+C0\\
C&=A1+B1\;.
\end{align*}$$

Since I’m really interested in $B+C$, I’d like to eliminate $A$; I can do that by substituting the first equation into each of the others. Now

$$\begin{align*}
(\lambda+B0+C1)0+C0&=0+B00+C10+C0\\
&=0+B00+C(\lambda+1)0\;,
\end{align*}$$

and similarly for the third equation, so we get the system

$$\begin{align*}
B&=0+B00+C(\lambda+1)0\\
C&=1+B(\lambda+0)1+C11\;.
\end{align*}$$

The $B00$ and $C11$ terms are very useful. From $B=X+B00$ we can deduce that $B$ can be (anything represented by) $X$, $X00$, $X(00)^2$, and so on — in short, $B=X(00)^*$, where $$X=0+C(\lambda+1)0=\big(\lambda+C(\lambda+1)\big)0\;.$$ Treating $C$ similarly, we can rewrite the system as

$$\begin{align*}
B&=\big(\lambda+C(\lambda+1)\big)0(00)^*\\
C&=\big(\lambda+B(\lambda+0)\big)1(11)^*\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now substitute the second equation into the first and vice versa:

$$\begin{align*}
B&=\Big(0+\big(\lambda+B(\lambda+0)\big)1(11)^*(\lambda+1)0\Big)(00)^*\\
C&=\Big(1+\big(\lambda+C(\lambda+1)\big)0(00)^*(\lambda+0)1\Big)(11)^*
\end{align*}$$

We can now expand the right-hand side of the first equation to get an equation of the form $B=X+BY$, which, as we saw earlier, can be rewritten $B=XY^*$:

$$\begin{align*}
B&=\Big(0+\big(\lambda+B(\lambda+0)\big)1(11)^*(\lambda+1)0\Big)(00)^*\\
&=0(00)^*+1(11)^*0(00)^*+1(11)^*10(00)^*+B\Big((\lambda+0)1(11)^*(\lambda+1)0(00)^*\Big)\\
&=\Big(\lambda+1(11)^*(\lambda+1)\Big)0(00)^*\Big((\lambda+0)1(11)^*(\lambda+1)0(00)^*\Big)^*\;.\tag{1}
\end{align*}$$

We’ve now eliminated $A,B$, and $C$ from the expression for $B$, and you can check against the DFA that the regular expression $(1)$ really does describe the words that end up in state $B$. (Note that I have not tried to simplify the expression; it’s likely that it can be simplified, perhaps quite significantly.)

Now see if you can follow this model to get a corresponding regular expression for $C$; the regular expression $B+C$ will then describe the language accepted by the DFA.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!! Could you maybe also take a look at my other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200782/are-the-propositions-right ?

Comment: @evinda: You’re very welcome. I’ll take a look, but I’m actually pretty weak on algorithms and computational complexity.